# Homomorphism or Anti-Homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I've been having the most difficult time with what ought to be the easiest of properties.  The setup is as follows:

let $G$ be a group and $X$ some set on which $G$ acts on the left.  Explicitly if $g,h\in G$ and $x \in X$ then $(gh,x) = g \cdot h \cdot x = g \cdot (h \cdot x)$ so that when $gh$ acts on $x$ we first act with $h$ and then with $g$.  In the group $\mathrm{Sym} (X)$, we compose left to right so that if $\sigma, \tau \in \mathrm{Sym} (X)$ and $x \in X$ then $(\sigma \tau)(x) = \sigma (\tau (x))$ i.e., first $\tau$, then $\sigma$.  I'm trying to prove that a map $\Phi : G \to \mathrm{Sym} (X)$ which I've defined is a group homomorphism.  I've shown that for $g,h \in G$ and $x \in X$ we have 
$$
\Phi (gh)(x) = (\Phi (g) \circ \Phi (h))(x)
$$
While this looks perfectly correct, that which is causing me stress is the fact that the particular group $G$ I'm working with is a fundamental group and as such there is a "handedness" to the group law: an element $g \in G$ is a homotopy class of a loop and if $h\in H$ then $gh$ means "first follow $g$, then follow $h$" (and then mod out by homotopy equivalence.)  In this case the displayed equation doesn't seem quite right since on the LHS we follow $g$ first, then $h$ whereas on the RHS we follow (the image of) $h$ and then (the image of) $g$.
Left vs. right actions have really been messing with me recently!

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Given that which I've written, is the displayed equation an example of a homomorphism or an anti-homomorphism?

Comment: Note that a set $X$ with a *right* $G$-action is the same as an antihomomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Such a map $\Phi$ is indeed a homomorphism.  You have shown that $\Phi(gh)=\Phi(g)\circ\Phi(h)$.  Since $\circ$ is the group operation on $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ ($\sigma\circ\tau$ is defined by the formula $(\sigma\circ\tau)(x)=\sigma(\tau(x))$, so it agrees with your definition of $\sigma\tau$), this says $\Phi$ preserves the group operation.